# Build C++ shared object when building Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, makefile

I'm trying to setup Eclipse to build a C++ library as a shared object *before* building my Android project.

I looked into how to do this through Android.mk but it seems I'd need to modify the C++ libraries make files to use android makefiles instead, which would require more time than available.

I've imported the source for the C++ library, and am able to build it through Eclipse, and in my Android projects Android.mk file I reference the location of the prebuilt shared object and it is installed correctly when running the app.

So is there some way to make Eclipse build the C++ project and then my Android project when I build just the Android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the most part, I solved my problem. First I had to import the native library project as a C++ project. Then, I changed the build directory through Eclipse to where my make file was for the library. Lastly, I made my project reference the native library by doing Properties->Project References and selecting the native library project.